# Can't get results due to typed literal (xsd:string) querying SPARQL from Jena;

Tags: java, xsd, sparql, jena, string-literals

I have my Virtuoso server running with loaded ontology, the following query works by pasting it to text field in sparql endpoint on the web (*ronto, the prefix of my ontology I skipped because of security reasons (sorry), but I'm sure it's defined correctly, because queries works but returns empty list which is an issue*):

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select distinct (str(?p) as ?theme) where {?s ronto:isin "id-XXXX"^^xsd:string; ronto:mainThemes ?p}
```

**the following doesn't work** (returns empty list); mind the skipped

> xsd:string

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select distinct (str(?p) as ?theme) where {?s ronto:isin "id-XXXX"; ronto:mainThemes ?p}
```

So, the **ISSUE**: I can't get result doing the same from Java, Jena deps are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

So, the toy-code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String isin = "id-XXXX";
        final ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
                "select ?p where {?s ronto:isin ?isin^^xsd:string; ronto:mainThemes ?p.}");
        qs.setBaseUri(base);
        qs.setNsPrefix("owl", "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#");
        qs.setNsPrefix("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#");
        qs.setNsPrefix("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
        qs.setNsPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");

        qs.setLiteral("isin", isin);

        System.out.println("Running as a query " +qs.asQuery());
        try (QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(publicSparqlEndpoint, qs.asQuery())) {
            final ResultSet resultSet = exec.execSelect();
            System.out.println(exec.getQuery());
            ResultSetFormatter.out(resultSet);
        }
        System.out.println("Running as a string " + qs.toString());
        try (QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(publicSparqlEndpoint, qs.toString())) {
            final ResultSet resultSet = exec.execSelect();
            System.out.println(exec.getQuery());
            ResultSetFormatter.out(resultSet);
        }
```

and output is

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>


SELECT  ?p
WHERE
  { ?s  ronto:isin        "id-XXXX" ;
        ronto:mainThemes  ?p
  }
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT  ?p
WHERE
  { ?s  ronto:isin        "id-XXXX" ;
        ronto:mainThemes  ?p
  }

-----
| p |
=====
-----
Running as a string
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?p where {?s ronto:isin "id-XXXX"^^xsd:string; ronto:mainThemes ?p.}

PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT  ?p
WHERE
  { ?s  ronto:isin        "id-XXXX" ;
        ronto:mainThemes  ?p
  }

-----
| p |
=====
-----
```

where p-boxes are empty list-results from the endpoint;

I tested simpler queries that are not based on typed literal (xsd:string here) and they gave me non-empty result;

So, it's easy to find that exec object has query with skipped *xsd:string*, which I guess is an issue of getting empty list as a result, but why does it work in that way and what is the clean approach to make a workaround?

**Solution** I got thanks to @AndyS (mind two changes: FILTER in query and QueryEngineHTTP):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String isin = "id-XXXX";
    final ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
            "select ?p where {?s ronto:isin ?X; ronto:mainThemes ?p. FILTER (?X= ?isin^^xsd:string)}");
    qs.setBaseUri(base);
    qs.setNsPrefix("owl", "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#");
    qs.setNsPrefix("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#");
    qs.setNsPrefix("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
    qs.setNsPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
    qs.setNsPrefix("ronto", "....");

    qs.setLiteral("isin", isin);

    System.out.println("Running as a string " + qs.toString());
    try (QueryEngineHTTP exec = new QueryEngineHTTP(publicSparqlEndpoint, qs.toString())) {
        final ResultSet resultSet = exec.execSelect();
        System.out.println(exec.getQuery());
        ResultSetFormatter.out(resultSet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RDF 1.1, strings without `xsd:string` and strings with `xsd:string` are the same RDF term.  It does not matter if you write the `^^xsd:string` or not.

ARQ prints queries without `^^xsd:string` and this is used for remote SPARQL call.

It looks like the Virtuoso instance is not compatible with RDF 1.1.

You can try a value-expression in your query:

```
{ ?s ronto:isin ?X;
     ronto:mainThemes ?p.
  FILTER ( ?X = "id-XXXX"^^xsd:string)
}
```

which works for RDF 1.0 and RDF 1.1 and mixtures of systems.

Alternatively, use `QueryEngineHTTP` directly, not `QueryExecutionFactory`.  This allows the app to pass in a string as the query that is sent to the remote endpoint without parsing or checking.

Comment: Thank you, it works only when I applied FILTER and use QueryEngineHTTP passing query as a string. @AndyS, you saved my day.